# Access Android application via Appium in the middle of Ranorex test suit

Tags: c#, appium, ranorex

Im using Ranorex for automating a Android application. In the middle of a test case flow application loads a google map and plot some data, Ranorex is failing to access the google map.

So im thinking of Using Appium to access the google map and get things done on this part.

Is it possible for Appium to connect with an application and invoke some actions in the middle of a user flow (without relaunching the application) ??

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, First you need to start Appium session with override flag + New command Timeout as much as possible. Execute the suite using Ranorex test suite, in the middle of the session, perform actions with the help of Appium and again pass on the control to Ranorex.

Helpful keys in Appium for this are:

- Override flag
- Timeout flag

Comment: mmm....sounds soo tricky